# How do I fix javascript SyntaxError in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

Okay, so I'm currently developing a bot for my discord server. It's going to be an anti-spam bot. I found this open source simple anti-spam bot written in Node.JS.

Link to project, there are two links:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-anti-spam
- https://github.com/Michael-J-Scofield/discord-anti-spam

When I try to run the bot.js I get this error in the console:

```
    maxDuplicatesWarning = 7,// Maximum amount of duplicate messages a user can send in a timespan before getting warned
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:599:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

I've tried removing the maxDuplicatesWarning line but then it just gives me an error of maxDuplicatesBan.

Here are my bot.js:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = "!"

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Bot service launched. Bot ${client.user.tag} is successfully activated!`);
client.user.setStatus("dnd");
client.user.setGame('Fidget Spinner');

var anti_spam = require("discord-anti-spam");

antispam(bot, {
  warnBuffer: 3, //Maximum amount of messages allowed to send in the interval time before getting warned.
  maxBuffer: 5, // Maximum amount of messages allowed to send in the interval time before getting banned.
  interval: 1000, // Amount of time in ms users can send a maximum of the maxBuffer variable before getting banned.
  warningMessage: "stopp å spamme eller kutter jeg av deg kuken.", // Warning message send to the user indicating they are going to fast.
  banMessage: "har blitt bannet for spamming, noen andre som vil?", // Ban message, always tags the banned user in front of it.
  maxDuplicatesWarning = 7,// Maximum amount of duplicate messages a user can send in a timespan before getting warned
  maxDuplicatesBan = 10 // Maximum amount of duplicate messages a user can send in a timespan before getting banned
});

client.login('private');
```

---

Here is the anti_spam.js:

```
const authors = [];
var warned = [];
var banned = [];
var messagelog = [];

/**
 * Add simple spam protection to your discord server.
 * @param  {Bot} bot - The discord.js CLient/bot
 * @param  {object} options - Optional (Custom configuarion options)
 * @return {[type]}         [description]
 */
module.exports = function (bot, options) {
  // Set options
  const warnBuffer = (options && options.prefix) || 3;)
  const maxBuffer = (options && options.prefix) || 5;)
  const interval = (options && options.interval) || 1000;)
  const warningMessage = (options && options.warningMessage) || "stop å spamme ellers kutter jeg av deg kuken.";
  const banMessage = (options && options.banMessage) || "har blit bannet for spamming, noen andre som vil?";
  const maxDuplicatesWarning = (options && options.duplicates || 7;)
  const maxDuplicatesBan = (options && options.duplicates || 10;)

  bot.on('message', msg => {

    if(msg.author.id != bot.user.id){
      var now = Math.floor(Date.now());
      authors.push({
        "time": now,
        "author": msg.author.id
      });
      messagelog.push({
        "message": msg.content,
        "author": msg.author.id
      });

      // Check how many times the same message has been sent.
      var msgMatch = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < messagelog.length; i++) {
        if (messagelog[i].message == msg.content && (messagelog[i].author == msg.author.id) && (msg.author.id !== bot.user.id)) {
          msgMatch++;
        }
      }
      // Check matched count
      if (msgMatch == maxDuplicatesWarning && !warned.includes(msg.author.id)) {
        warn(msg, msg.author.id);
      }
      if (msgMatch == maxDuplicatesBan && !banned.includes(msg.author.id)) {
        ban(msg, msg.author.id);
      }

      matched = 0;

      for (var i = 0; i < authors.length; i++) {
        if (authors[i].time > now - interval) {
          matched++;
          if (matched == warnBuffer && !warned.includes(msg.author.id)) {
            warn(msg, msg.author.id);
          }
          else if (matched == maxBuffer) {
            if (!banned.includes(msg.author.id)) {
              ban(msg, msg.author.id);
            }
          }
        }
        else if (authors[i].time < now - interval) {
          authors.splice(i);
          warned.splice(warned.indexOf(authors[i]));
          banned.splice(warned.indexOf(authors[i]));
        }
        if (messagelog.length >= 200) {
          messagelog.shift();
        }
      }
    }
  });

  /**
   * Warn a user
   * @param  {Object} msg
   * @param  {string} userid userid
   */
  function warn(msg, userid) {
    warned.push(msg.author.id);
    msg.channel.send(msg.author + " " + warningMessage);
  }

  /**
   * Ban a user by the user id
   * @param  {Object} msg
   * @param  {string} userid userid
   * @return {boolean} True or False
   */
  function ban(msg, userid) {
    for (var i = 0; i < messagelog.length; i++) {
      if (messagelog[i].author == msg.author.id) {
        messagelog.splice(i);

      }
    }

    banned.push(msg.author.id);

    var user = msg.channel.guild.members.find(member => member.user.id === msg.author.id);
    if (user) {
      user.ban().then((member) => {
        msg.channel.send(msg.author + " " +banMessage);
        return true;
     }).catch(() => {
        msg.channel.send("du har ikke rettigheter til å banne " + msg.author + " for spamming.");
        return false;
     });
    }
  }

}
```

Can someone please help me solve this problem?
Thanks :D

***NEW UPDATE!***

Now I'm getting this error:

```
const warnBuffer = (options && options.prefix) || 3;)
                                                      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:599:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Bots\fambot\bot.js:9:17)
```

Comment: Dude .. you have "=" where it should be ":"

Comment: This is basic JavaScript. Don't blindly copy and paste code. It's better to understand it first.

Comment: @TestHard There are so many more errors. Please try to solve them first yourself.

Comment: I'd really recommend learning JavaScript a bit better before attempting a project of this scale - if you don't understand the syntax, you're just going to constantly be tripping over yourself. Alternatively, if you want to stick with it, I'd recommend cutting down your code to the bare minimum and reintroducing it section-by-section so you can see where the problems are being caused.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
antispam(bot, {
  warnBuffer: 3, //Maximum amount of messages allowed to send in the interval time before getting warned.
  maxBuffer: 5, // Maximum amount of messages allowed to send in the interval time before getting banned.
  interval: 1000, // Amount of time in ms users can send a maximum of the maxBuffer variable before getting banned.
  warningMessage: "stopp å spamme eller kutter jeg av deg kuken.", // Warning message send to the user indicating they are going to fast.
  banMessage: "har blitt bannet for spamming, noen andre som vil?", // Ban message, always tags the banned user in front of it.
  maxDuplicatesWarning: 7,// Maximum amount of duplicate messages a user can send in a timespan before getting warned
  maxDuplicatesBan: 10 // Maximum amount of duplicate messages a user can send in a timespan before getting banned
});
```

You must assign value to a key in object with `:` not `=`

UPDATE:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Bot service launched. Bot ${client.user.tag} is successfully activated!`)
});
```

Comment: OMG! You have too much syntax error! Please check your syntax first!

Comment: @TestHard - Paste blocks of code into http://jshint.com/ and fix all the errors it shows you.

Answer (score 0):

try use utf-8 character sets. I getting like this in my project

Comment: How do I change it to utf-8 character?

Comment: I change in phpstorm or webstorm in bottom screen